# android:layout_weight with vertical linearlayout

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm trying to create a android layout like:

[####EditText###][Button]

[####listview#####]

For that i'm using weight, but the following xml is giving me something very strang like:

[editText][button][ListView]

Someone know why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:weightSum="10"
     >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/nova_lista"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:hint="@string/new_list_hint">

    </EditText>

    <Button android:id="@+id/nova_lista_botao"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/new_list"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_of_lists"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `android:orientation="vertical"`

and you are specifying `android:layout_width` equal to `0dp`.

For vertical `layout layout_height` should be `0 dp` and for `Horizontal` layout `layout_width` should be 0 dp if you are using `weight` in LinearLayout.

Put `EditText` and `Button` in separate `Horizontal` Layout. Use below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
     >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10"
     >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/nova_lista"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:hint="@string/new_list_hint">

    </EditText>

    <Button android:id="@+id/nova_lista_botao"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/new_list"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_of_lists"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff" >    


    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/nova_lista"       
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/nova_lista_botao"
        android:inputType="text"       
        android:hint="something">

    </EditText>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/nova_lista_botao"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Hello"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_of_lists"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/nova_lista" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

1.Set your main layout is RelativeLayout

2.Create LinarLayout and move EditText and Button to LinerLayout

3.Set LinerLayout is "@+id/top_layout" and set listview is

> android:layout_below="@+id/top_layout"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@drawable/background"
   android:weightSum="10" >

    <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/top_layout"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
           android:id="@+id/nova_lista"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="9"
           android:hint="@string/new_list_hint"
           android:inputType="text" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/nova_lista_botao"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/new_list" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
       android:id="@+id/list_of_lists"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/top_layout" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```